# Daedalus for testnets and why not use Mainnet as test environment

Tags: cardano-cli, daedalus, testnet, mainnet

Last year I set up a Cardano testnet as part of the Plutus Pioneers program. I'm now using my Daedalus installation to experiment with the cardano-cli, which I am finding much easier, with the added benefit of knowing that my transactions actually work in the real world. The transaction cost so far is trivial. Is there any reason *not* to use the mainnet for R&D, learning, and experimentation? I can't imagine I'm stressing the network, and I'm putting only my own ADA at risk (little 2-5 ADA transactions). I can imagine I could clutter up the blockchain with pointless metadata.

Closely related, is there a way to use Daedalus to talk to the testnet?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the Testnet version (all Testnets) of Daedalus from [here](https://testnets.cardano.org/cardano-testnet/daedalus-testnet).

You can request testing funds from the [faucet](https://testnets.cardano.org/en/testnets/cardano/tools/faucet/), this way you never risk any of your Mainnet ADA, even if it is a small amount.

At the end testnet are created for that reason.

If you want to make your test environment the most similar to Mainnet, use Preprod environment.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a very good answer for why not to use the mainnet for learning and experimentation. Fortunately I did not learn this thru experience but by reading about other's difficulties.
If ADA is sent to a script, and no datum/hash is sent, or if the order of parameters is incorrect, the ADA will be locked forever in the script (assuming the script does not also have a fail-safe endpoint built in to return funds after a time if no other endpoint is triggered).
Perhaps this problem has already been fixed as it was discussed a year ago, but I'm sure the risk remains. Fortunately I am not at the point yet of experimenting with scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small local testnet yourself using the [cardano-private-testnet-setup](https://github.com/woofpool/cardano-private-testnet-setup)

When the network starts up it starts ~3 Nodes and creates a few wallets which then can be used for your tests.